# CSS3 moz-kit animation

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS3 animation that works in Chrome

```
 .circle-label-rotate {
                -webkit-animation-name: rotateThis;
                -webkit-animation-duration:.5s;
                -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
            }
```

Now, how would that work on Mozilla Firefox -- I think using [keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@keyframes). But I keep getting errrors. How would you do the Firefox-equivilant of the above code?

I have tried this:

```
-moz-animation-duration: 3s;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
-moz-animation-name: slidein;
-webkit-animation-name: slidein;
```

Comment: try posting it to a http://www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `-moz-` prefix.

```
-moz-animation-name: rotateThis;
-moz-animation-duration:.5s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;  
-moz-animation-timing-function:linear;

@-moz-keyframes rotateThis 
{ Some css. }
```

Comment: +1 although the issue may very well be in animation declaration which has been left out of the original question

Answer (score 0):

- the extension -webkit- would work well in Chrome and Safari
- the -moz- would work in Mozilla Firefox
- the -o- would work in Opera
- the -ms- would work in IE (but I'm not sure if it supports yet or not)